# Двумерный массив C#

Tags: c#

В этой программе

```
using System;

class TwoD
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int t, i;
        int[,] table = new int[3, 4];

        for (t = 0; t < 3; ++t)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
            {
                table[t, i] = (t * 4) + i + 1; // 
                Console.Write(table[t, i] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

не понял логику этой части кода `table[t, i] = (t * 4) + i+ 1;`
массив table[t, i] присваивает значение (0 * 4) + 0 + 1   (получается 1). Помогите разобраться.

Comment: Так а что должно быть? Если так написали, то так и есть... Чего (какого результата) Вы ожидаете от работы этого кода?

Comment: Эта программа написана в книге Г. Шилдта.

Comment: И что из того? В ней не написано, что Вы должны получить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это просто игра с индексами для получения возрастающей последовательности чисел.Например при t[0,0]=(0*4)+0+1 получается t[0,0]=1,далее i становится равным единицы(так как цикл вложенный). При i=1 получается следующее значение  t[0,1]=(0*4)+1+1. Так получается t[0,1]=2. И так далее пока верхний цикл не завершится

Comment: когда t увеличивается на один то (t * 4)  + I + 1      тут (t*4) будет равно 4. Так зачем вообще это нужно (t*4) + i + 1

Comment: А если t  будет равно два? Тогда оказывается t очень даже нужно для того что бы возрастающая последовательность сохранялась.. На бумажке проделайте за машину ее действия и увидите что без t в этой формуле ни как..

Answer (score 2):

Получится массив `table[,]`:

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9 10 11 12
```